# Adding leading zero in a specific field from a text file with regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, grep

I want to change everything before a special character for every "status" column in that case:

{"name":0.main","tablespace":"UNDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":.04},
    {"name":0.main","tablespace":"REDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":0},

In that case I want to change .04 to be 0.04. I tried with sed:

```
sed 's/:./:0./g'
```

But the result for second row shows "0." in the status column.

How do I change only the status column and everything with **.anynumber** to be replaced with **0.anynumber**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `awk` is more suited able here. Your input is separated by commas and the key, value pair where `status` is the key is the sixth field `"status":.04`. With the following script the substitution only takes place on the required field and replace all `:.` with `:0.` i.e making sure all decimal values have leading zeros if previously absence:

```
$ awk '{sub(/:[.]/,":0.",$6)}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `.[digit]*` to `0.[digit]*` for a specific field with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's/("status":)(\.[0-9]+)/\10\2/' file
```

```
$cat file
{"name":0.main","tablespace":"UNDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":.04},
{"name":0.main","tablespace":"REDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":0},

$sed -r 's/("status":)(\.[0-9]+)/\10\2/' file
{"name":0.main","tablespace":"UNDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":0.04},
{"name":0.main","tablespace":"REDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":0},
```

Comment: @sudo_O you are completely right:"status" is much safer. I added field information. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -pe 's/("status"\s*:\s*)(\.[0-9]+)(?=\s*,|\s*})/${1}0${2}/' input
{"name":0.main","tablespace":"UNDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":0.04},
{"name":0.main","tablespace":"REDO","size":"500","maxsize":"65536","usedsize":"29","status":0},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in GNU sed,

```
sed 's/\(.*status":.*\)\(\.[0-9]\+\)/\10\2/' file.txt
```

If you want to affect this changes in original file,

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(.*status":.*\)\(\.[0-9]\+\)/\10\2/' file.txt
```

Comment: Using `.*` in your search pattern happens to work because status is at the end of the input as given in the question, but if it occurs earlier, your pattern may produce unexpected results.